# Failed to start Raise network interfaces after upgrading to 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, ethernet

I just upgraded a virtual 14.04 server machine to 16.04. After rebooting the VM I see the following error:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
 See 'systemctl status networking.service' for details
```

After login I can run the mentioned command and get the following output (image as I'm not able to connect):

[image]

The configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` looks fine - featuring the manually configured eth0 (not using dhcp here)

What makes me wondering is that `ifconfig -a` lists

- ens160
- lo

Where I would expect

- eth0
- lo

Trying to up the eth0 device via

```
sudo ifup -v eth0
```

outputs:

```
...
Cannot find device "eth0"
Failed to bring up eth0.
```

The virtual wired network device itself is still configured in the VM itself as it was before.

`ip link` shows as well `lo` and `ens160` - where `ens160` has the mac address configured in vmware for the single configured virtual network device.

#### UPDATE

I am able to solve the issue if i change all references of eth0 in `/etc/network/interfaces` to ens160.

**BUT** - this feels wrong for me for several reasons:

1. I would like to understand this problem
2. I would like to stick to eth0 instead of ens160

So please can someone explain this change, which didn't happen to several other 14.04 machines on the same server which I also upgraded to 16.04.

Comment: Might be duplicate to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/704361/why-is-my-network-interface-named-enp0s25-instead-of-eth0

Comment: A similar description of the fix is here: https://askubuntu.com/a/830163/543586

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Reason

The problem was caused by Predictable-Network-Interface-Names from systemd/udev.

## Possible solution

According to [this source](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) you can either:

- You disable the assignment of fixed names, so that the unpredictable kernel names are used again. For this, simply mask udev's rule file for the default policy: ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
- You create your own manual naming scheme, for example by naming your interfaces "internet0", "dmz0" or "lan0". For that create your own .link files in /etc/systemd/network/, that choose an explicit name or a better naming scheme for one, some, or all of your interfaces. See systemd.link(5) for more information.
- You pass the net.ifnames=0 on the kernel command line

## Applied solutions

I did create a new file `10-rename-network.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` and added the following content to it:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", NAME="eth0"
```

where

- `eth0` = desired network interface name, used in `/etc/network/interfaces`
- `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff` = hardware mac address of the network device

I'd recommend rebooting after completing this to make sure the change is sticky.

Comment: I discovered I had to run `update-initramfs -u` to get my changes to take effect

Comment: On my Debian system the file is '/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules'

Comment: @Aneel does your update code work for `the upredictable kernel names` in solution 1? Seems not.

Comment: My impression is that you can stick with your "old" device name such as `wlan0` in `10-rename-network.rules` and do not have to "invent" one.

Answer (score 16):

Solved by changing file /etc/network/interfaces.d/setup 
from:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: I missed the `/etc/network/interfaces.d/setup` and assumed `interfaces`

Comment: Why not enter this data with `allow-hotplug` directly in `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: worked like a magic thanks!

Comment: cat: /etc/network/interfaces.d/setup: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

In my case this problem was related to trying to bring up my bridge `br0`. I had forgotten to do this:

```
sudo apt-get install bridge-utils
```

before and so my adapter couldn't get started.

Comment: This is different from OP's problem. I'm not sure this answer belongs to this question!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to delete/modify the udev cache for persistent/consistent network interface names, located here:
 `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`