# Broadcom NetXtreme II BCM5716 Ethernet controller unclaimed after update to 16.04 server

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, broadcom

I am running a Ubuntu server machine (Dell Poweredge R410) with a Broadcom NetXtreme II BCM5716 Ethernet controller (2 ethernet ports, wired). I recently decided to upgrade the machine from 14.04 to 16.04 (using `do-release-uprade` with no additional options). Which was a huge mistake.  At first booting did not succeed unless using recovery mode, however, through recovery mode I can boot with linux kernel 3.0.0-17 without issues (proceed with normal boot). Which is a kernel from ubuntu 11 ([List of Ubuntu Versions with Corresponding Linux Kernel Version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517136/list-of-ubuntu-versions-with-corresponding-linux-kernel-version))?. Regardless, I can start the machine, but it appears I cannot activate the networking. As the server is in a server farm which is not easy to reach for me, I'd like to get the networking up and do further debugging from home. Any suggestions are warmly welcome, I've included all (community) info and what I've tried so far below. Everything is hand-typed (as I have no network on the server), so apologies if typos. I am willing to try additional suggestions and have copied the home drive to an external hard drive. If a complete fresh install of ubuntu 16.04 server is my best solution, please let me know as well (although I'd rather avoid it).

### System info

`lsb_release -a`

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux [servername] 3.0.0-17-server #30-Ubuntu [system date and time] x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces`

```
#This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
#and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces (5)

#The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

`ip link` and `ifconfig -a` only list the loopback interface.
`dmesg | grep eth0` returns nothing

in `lspci -v` I see for my two ethernet ports:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controoler: Broadcom corporation NetXtreme II BCM5716 Gigabit ethernet (rev20)
    DeviceName: Embedded NIC 1
    Subsystem: Dell PowerEdge R410 BCM5716 Gigabit Ethernet
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 36
    Memory at da000000 (64 bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable-Count=1/16 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=9 Masked-
    Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Device serial Number [serial number]
    Capabilities: [110] Advanced error reporting
    Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
    Kernel modules: bnx2
01:00.1 Ethernet controoler: Broadcom corporation NetXtreme II BCM5716 Gigabit ethernet (rev20)
    DeviceName: Embedded NIC 2
    Subsystem: Dell PowerEdge R410 BCM5716 Gigabit Ethernet
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 48
    Memory at dc000000 (64 bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable-Count=1/16 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=9 Masked-
    Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Device serial Number [serial number]
    Capabilities: [110] Advanced error reporting
    Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
    Kernel modules: bnx2
```

`journalctcl -b` states an error for getting hardwer adress for "eth0": No such device as well as a permision denied error to create socket for "eth0" and ultimately failed to raise network interfaces.

`lshw -C network` shows that the devices are unclaimed:

```
*-network:0 UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: NetXtreme II BCM5716 Gigabit controller
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physcial id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 20
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33 MHz
   capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory: [memory adress]
```

and something comparable for the other network port

### What I have tried so far

1. `rmmod bnx2` and subsequently `modprobe bxn2` results in errors in `dmesg`: `Can't load firmware file bnx2/bnx2-mips-09-6.2.1a.fw` which leads in the disabling of the PCI INT (both of them). There is indeed no such directory even in `/lib/firmware`, only a `bxn2x` folder which does not have such files avai
2. add `bce` to `/etc/modules` had no effect

### Other posts checked in search of a solution

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1566431
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man4/bce.4freebsd.html
- [Failed to start Raise network interfaces after upgrading to 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824376/failed-to-start-raise-network-interfaces-after-upgrading-to-16-04)
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1314693

Comment: you need the firmware file to go along with the module, which has to be compiled to the kernel that you are using. do you have the headers for the working kernel?

Comment: @ravery: I do not know, how can I find out?

Comment: Interface name has changed. It is not `eth0`. What does `ifconfig` show?

Comment: @Pilot6 `ifconfig` only shows me the `lo` device (local loopback).

Comment: @ravery Why are you posting this kind of things? What firmware are you talking about and how it is "compiled to the kernel"

Comment: @pilot the driver is compiled to kernel, the firmware comes with it "dmesg: Can't load firmware file bnx2/bnx2-mips-09-6.2.1a.fw"

Comment: I found it. Good catch! Hold on, I will fix it!

Comment: @pilot6 --  he has also had a kernel regression  ver 3.0.0. if the driver isn't in the kernel, he'll need to compile the module

Comment: The new kernel requires new firmware file. I found it.

Comment: @FMKerckhof I found a workaround.

Comment: @ravery Nothing needs to be compiled. OP needs to get the firmware.

Answer (score 5):

This is an Ubuntu bug that should be reported to Launchpad by running `ubuntu-bug linux-firmware`.

The problem is that the 3.3+ kernels require new firmware files. The files are available in upstream `linux-firmware` git, but are not backported to Ubuntu `linux-firmware` package.

A workaround is to download the upstream git and take firmware form there.

Clone the git repo by

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

and copy the `bnx2` directory to `/lib/firmware` on your server.

Threre is already a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1008749) on this issue.

It is marked as "fixed", but it is actually not any more. I don't see the bnx2 firmware in any of the supported `linux-firmware` packages. So I suggest to make a new bug report.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will have to clone it on another machine and bring it on a stick to the data center (as I have no networking whatsoever on that server). Reporting to launchpad will only be possible after I restore networking. I will get back to you, but it might be a while.

Comment: in the end, again the same result happened after adding the `bnx2` folder to `/lib/firmware`. Hence, I had no other resort as to backup the home drives and start anew with a fresh install of Ubuntu server 16.04.3. Now of course, I need to reinstall all software, but at least the machine is properly online again.

Comment: Just thought I'd add this worked for me with an old Dell PowerEdge 1950 and Ubuntu 18.04.3. I created a new FAT USB stick and copied the appropriate *.fw files to the USB stick. Then I manually mounted USB stick during installer (using Alt+F2 to get to a shell) and copied those *.fw files into `/lib/firmware/bnx2/*.fw` and then the installer could fetch an IP from DHCPv4 and install continued!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! same thing happen with old ibm x3550 model. i will update the status later.

Answer (score 2):

We had this same issue. Only thing that solved it was to update the kernel to something above 4.9.0.  We went with 4.9.73.  Steps:

- Go to [the Ubuntu kernel website](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/)
- Download 3 debs to a folder somewhere (adjusting for system type)

  - `linux-headers-4.9.73-040973_4.9.73-040973.201712291730_all.deb`
  - `linux-image-4.9.73-040973-generic_4.9.73-040973.201712291730_amd64.deb`
  - `linux-headers-4.9.73-040973-generic_4.9.73-040973.201712291730_amd64.deb`
- Install the debs and run `update-grub`:

  ```
  cd /path/to/folder/where/you/put/the/debs
  sudo dpkg -i *.deb
  sudo update-grub
  reboot
  ```
- Drink beer to celebrate your greatness

Situation solution starting point:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1643558